# Having trouble with AppDelegate didFinishLoadingWithOptions execution order/timing

Tags: ios, swift

I'm having an issue with this code (I have it in didFinishLaunchingWithOptions). I need it to finish executing the code inside before the app continues because it sets up some critical things in core data. It sends this to the background though and starts running the rest of the app and it doesn't finish quick enough for the data to be usable.

```
DataManager.getDataWithSuccess { (data) -> Void in 
//code to execute here
}
```

How can I force the app to wait for this code to finish before moving on?

Comment: You ***shouldn't***.

Comment: You should do this asynchronously. Otherwise your user interface would freeze while this does it's thing leading to a very bad user experience.

Comment: It *is* being done asynchronously.  The asker simply wants to wait for the asynchronous code to complete before returning from the method.  The user interface isn't interactive before `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` anyway.

Comment: @nhgrif then what should I do to ensure that this beings on app start and completes before the first view after the launch screen appears?

Comment: Blocking while waiting for an asynchronous event is not very asynchronous at all. I prefer to load the user interface, show an activity indicator, and load the data asynchronously in the background.

Comment: "at all" is quite strong @paulvs.  If this is the first thing dispatched and there are several other things occurring on the main thread, it could very well be the case that the code in the background *has* completed and we don't wait at all.  It's *definitely* bad, but to say it's not asynchronous "at all" is slightly misleading.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You shouldn't block the `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` method from returning so that it can wait on an asynchronous task.  It's crucially important to note that iOS applications are only given a limited amount of time to complete launching before the application is killed by the operating system.

An approach I have used in the past when waiting on asynchronous things to happen that need to happen before I *really* launch my app is to create a `LaunchViewController`.  The interface for this view controller matches perfectly to the app's splash screen.  From an end-user perspective, you can't even tell we've left the splash screen.

Here, we do any set up code such as asking your `DataManager` to get data.  Then, when it (and any other set up actions) completes, you simply present the next view controller in much the same way you'd move between any other view controllers.

A huge positive side effect here is that you can have *much* nice looking animations from your splash screen into the first screen of your application.